# На какой стороне лучше обрабатывать ввод данных в форму авторизации?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, frontend, form

Пишу сайт на Flask. Добрался до написания личного кабинета пользователя.

Отправляю данные формы логина через ajax в бэк. И вот самый вопрос: могу ли я обработать правильность введённых данных в фронтэнде через JS, и уже отправить проверенные данные в метод фласка, для дальнейшей обработки в бд ? И как лучше делать в этом случае ?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все окончательные проверки должны осуществляться перед вставкой в базу данных, то есть на бэкенде, а на фронтенде должны быть проверки как для улучшения отзывчивости, так и для предотвращения отправки лишних запросов на сервер.

Comment: Большое спасибо, приму к сведению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень крутое правило:

> Клиент всегда должен предварительно обработать данные перед отправкой
> и, по возможности, проверить их на правильность. В случае ввода
> неверных данных вывести ошибку
>
> Сервер **НИКОГДА** не должен доверять клиенту и **ОБЯЗАН** повторно
> валидировать данные перед **каким либо** действиями с ними. Если данные
> окажутся невалидными, сервер должен отправить ошибку в формате,
> который клиент сможет показать конечному пользователю

Comment: Большое спасибо. Приму к сведению.

Comment: @MEXANIZM100, если вам помог ответ, не забудьте пометить его галочкой.

Comment: Да, я пометил, ещё раз большое спасибо. Просто интересно, вдруг кто-то ещё выскажется.